# Multiple rows of SQL in single row under different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find the below example:

```
Empid.   Compcode.     Amount
101.        Basic.     1000
101.        Hra.       200
102.        Basic.     1200
102.        Hra.       200
102.        Medical.   100
```

I would like to format the data as shown below:

```
Emplid     basic.  Hra.      Medical
101.       1000.   200.     
102.       1200.   200.      100
```

Is there a way to generate this output using Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will solve by using PIVOT in SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       Empid,Compcode,Amount FROM TableName
) AS S
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR Compcode IN ('Basic', 'Hra', 'Medical')
)AS pvt
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys..SQL solved using pivot suggestions.

Comment: @shaik_mustafa ..Please marke as solved if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT
    x.Emplid,
    MAX(DECODE(x.Compcode, 'Basic.', x.Amount)) AS Basic,
    MAX(DECODE(x.Compcode, 'Hra.', x.Amount)) AS Hra,
    MAX(DECODE(x.Compcode, 'Medical.', x.Amount)) AS Medical,  
    FROM
    (
      SELECT a.Emplid,
             a.Compcode,
             a.Amount
      FROM   your_table a
    )As x
GROUP BY x.Emplid;
```